# How does the browser differentiate between a public and a private ip?

Tags: ipv4, ip

Say for example my system's private ip is 192.168.75.5 and I want to open a website whose public ip is also 192.168.75.5. Now, if I type the ip on my browser and hit enter my local system would show up.

How will the browser come to know that I want to open the website with the public ip 192.168.75.5 instead of the local system.

Comment: Public IP addresses are unique. You will not run into that situation with public addresses, and ISPs will not route private IP addresses on the public Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to reach your locally hosted server is using the 127.0.0.1 IP address (localhost loopback). The best way to check the status of an externally hosted server is to navigate to that pages domain name or IP address directly.

IP Addresses are defined by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA). Your ISP can sell you addresses which they have acquired through their local internet registry.

Inside of a company or home network, it does not make sense to purchase an IP address for every single device that connects to the internet. Instead, the private network uses a special set of IP addresses for their internal use, and then **net address translation** takes place, so that all of the internal private IP addresses share the same external public IP address.

There are three sets of private IP Addresses you can use:

```
 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

In this way, you can use the 192.168.1.1/24 network for your home network, and your neighbor can also use the 192.168.1.1/24 network, but when you communicate with eachother, it is your public IP addresses which are the actual communication endpoints.

With that being said, 192.168.75.5 will never be a public IP address. Also, the browser does not determine whether an IP is "Inside" or "Outside" your network, this takes place at a lower level, when the the TCP/IP protocol determines whether the network ID on the packet matches the network ID on the local segment, or if it has to be forwarded up to the default gateway.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a public adress looking like 192.168.X.X as they are not routed on the Internet.

Read this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958825.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Browsers, and almost all other applications, don't know (or care) if the address is public or private.  To a browser, the computer and network just presents a stream of data -- that's what the meaning of layers is all about.

At the network layer, IP addresses are all the same -- the idea of public and private has no meaning to computers.  Fundamentally, either the address is on the local network, or it isn't -- and needs to be routed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little...

Comment: Which part are you confused about?

Comment: I didn't get this part - Fundamentally, either the address is on the local network, or it isn't -- and needs to be routed.

Comment: All IP devices -- PCs, routers, cameras, toasters -- all work the same way:  when they have a packet to forward, they first look in their routing table to determine which interface they use (if they have more than one).  Then they determine if they can forward the packet to the destination on the local subnet, or they need to forward it to the gateway (next hop) device on that subnet.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your question is actually about duplicate IP addressing.  If your system has the same IP address as a remote system, it will always choose itself because it believes that it owns that IP address and will never consider a remote system as having that IP.